# Web Server IIS Error Signed

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

Anyone experience with this situation, I am really new for the Windows Environment.

On the Server Manager in Windows Server 2003 OS, on the role section I saw the WEB IIS Server with cross signed (red) what is that mean? Is that mean the installation of the IIS corrupted, cause before on last week I never saw this.

If is not a big problem, I will get to go to installing the PHP and connectin to MSSQL

Thanks,
da_root